# Environment variables not injecting at buildtime for NestJS Docker image using Docker-compose for production

Tags: node.js, docker, docker-compose

The problem. I want to build my NestJS application for production and use Docker-compose to inject the environment variables at build time. This is so I know I can inject env vars so when I move to Kubernetes I can use the env: name and value option in my deployment.yaml. But I am having problems - the environment variables aren't being 'transferred' to the Docker container when I run the full file, aka both stages.

Below is my Dockerfile. I want to pass in my DATABASE_URI which points to ElephantSQL

```
FROM node:alpine AS development

WORKDIR /src/app

ARG DATABASE_URI
ENV DATABASE_URI=$DATABASE_URI

COPY package*.json ./

RUN npm install

COPY . . 

# Run this command regardless so if prod is run, its cached
RUN npm run build

######################################################
FROM node:alpine as production

ARG NODE_ENV=production
ENV NODE_ENV=$NODE_ENV

WORKDIR /src/app

COPY package*.json ./

RUN npm install --only=prod

COPY . .

COPY --from=development /src/app/dist ./dist

CMD ["node", "dist/main"]
```

And my Docker-compose

```
server:
    build:
      context: ./server
      args:
        - DATABASE_URI=postgres://bingbong@bingbong.db.elephantsql.com/bingbong

    ports:
      - "5000:5000"
```

Going into the logs of the server, I am getting connection refused as app.module.ts cannot find the environment variable.

Here is my app.module.ts section for connecting to the database.

```
      name: 'default',
      type: 'postgres',
      port: 5432,
      url: process.env.DATABASE_URI,
      synchronize: true,
      logging: true,
      entities: [src/**/*ts],
    }),
```

I am wondering if what I am doing wrong, as when I target the development stage of the dockerfile, I can connect to the database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I realised what I was doing wrong - I was not passing in the environment variables into the production stage of the Dockerfile. The env vars are not 'copied' from the development stage to the production stage. Below fixed it.

```
######################################################
FROM node:alpine as production

ARG NODE_ENV=production
ENV NODE_ENV=$NODE_ENV

ARG DATABASE_URI
ENV DATABASE_URI=$DATABASE_URI

WORKDIR /src/app

COPY package*.json ./

RUN npm install --only=prod

COPY . .

COPY --from=development /src/app/dist ./dist

CMD ["node", "dist/main"]
```

And then passing them in my K8s deployment.yaml file as the following

```
spec:
      containers:
        - name: myapp
          image: myapp:1.0
          ports:
            - containerPort: 5000
          env:
            - name: DATABASE_URI
              value: "postgres://bingbong@bingbong.db.elephantsql.com/bingbong"
```